# clang-tooling: How to check if a field is an incomplete type on construction?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-ast-matchers

I want to write a matcher, which excludes classes containing incomplete types like:
`std::unique_ptr<ForwardDeclared>`, but it is not identified as one, because it is a template type (I think so). Does anyone know how to circumvent this?

Minimal code:

```cpp
// ...
class MoveDefaultToDecl: public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
// ...

public:
    void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& r) override {
        // ...
        auto const* class_decl = r.Nodes.getNodeAs<CXXRecordDecl>("method-class");
        auto iter = std::find_if(class_decl->field_begin(), class_decl->field_end(),
                                 [](auto const& field) { return field->getType()->isIncompleteType(); });
        if (iter != class_decl->field_end()) {
            return;
        }
        // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

`test.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class H {
    H();
    ~H() = delete;
};

class MyType;

class K {
    K();
    ~K();
    std::unique_ptr<MyType> ptr_;
};
```

`test.cpp`

```cpp
#include "test.h"

class MyType {
    // But not here:
    MyType() = default;
    // But not here:
    ~MyType() = default;
    int i;
};

// CHECK: :[[@LINE+1]]:3: note: "xyz" binds here
H::H() = default;

// But not here
K::K() = default; // Actually binds here

// But not here
K::~K() = default; // Actually binds here
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Incomplete>` *is* a complete type—just one whose destructor mustn’t be instantiated until `Incomplete` is completed.

Comment: You are right, now I just don't know how to correct that properly without reducing the readability. You can edit my question if you want.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean to ask, so I can’t edit it to say what you mean.

Comment: I want to move `= default` statements from the source to the header files. But I want to exclude those, which depend on the instantiation of used methods. For  `std::unique_ptr<Incomplete>` it's the destructor, but there are other types. 
So I want to prevent to move the instantiation of a method before the completion of its declaration.

Comment: I don’t think there’s any way to tell in general which instantiations will need what functions (or what types to be complete).